# How to fix incorrect split normals for extruding reigons

Tags: modeling, mesh, normals, extrude

So I am working on the top lid of a treasure trunk. The treasure trunk has 4 thick leather bands around the object.

My problem is that when I try to extrude the 4 bands outwards for thickness, 11/12 of the corners are extruding out the wrong way.

I have toggled on the display for split normals (the ones on vertices) and noticed that the one good corner has purple normals while the rest of the object has blue split normals. I have googled a bunch and found no good resource for explaining this to me. Please help!

Note: I tried to flip the color of the split normals on the bad corners and instead flipped them inward so you cant really see them so well in the images.

**Treasure trunk**
[image: treasure trunk]

**Extrude faces along normals**
[image: Extrude faces along normals]

**The one good corner**
[image: The one good corner]

**Notice the only corner with purple split normals?**
[image]

Comment: What you seem to have done accidentally is using the tool "Extrude Individual Faces" and then aborting the action by right-clicking or hitting Esc. This way, extruded faces are created but stay in place with the original faces you extruded. You can tell it was "Extrude Individual Faces" because there are dots on the edges between selected faces in a face loop selection. Anyway, that's just for explanation, the given answer by @KickAir8p should get rid of the problem.

Comment: That's a more thorough explanation than mine, thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have some duplicated geometry (can happen when extruding without moving the faces without realizing it, and then extruding again).  Select everything in the object and Merge by Distance (M key, bottom option), that should remove the extras.  Then try your extrusion again.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I dont fully understand the merge by distance solution but i will look up an explanation.